How can the same property in a prototyp chain have different values?
Today, during some testing, I was interested in seeing all properties of an Error object.
I wrote this Method to get all available properties, not caring about 'hasOwnProperty'.
/**
 * Get all properties of an object and don't care about enumerable or prototyp.
 *
 * @internal
 * @param {object} obj
 * @return {[string, unknown][]}
 */
export function getAllProperties(obj: object): [string, unknown][] {
  const properties: [string, unknown][] = [];
  const prototypChain: string[] = [];
  let currentObj = obj;

  while (currentObj !== Object.prototype && currentObj !== null) {
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(currentObj).forEach((key) => {
      if (prototypChain.length > 0) {
        // @ts-expect-error I want it this way!
        properties.push([`${prototypChain.join('.')}.${key}`, currentObj[key]]);
      } else {
        // @ts-expect-error I want it this way!
        properties.push([key, currentObj[key]]);
      }
    });
    currentObj = Object.getPrototypeOf(currentObj);
    prototypChain.push('prototyp');
  }
  return properties;
}

Imagine my surprise when I used it to look at an error thrown with new Error('...').
{
  stack: "Error: This is a test error
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/.../Entwicklung/Bit/bit-log/src/appender/__tests__/FileAppender.spec.ts:256:13)",
  message: "This is a test error",
  prototyp.constructor: [Function function Error() { [native code] }],
  prototyp.name: "Error",
  prototyp.message: "",
  prototyp.toString: [Function function toString() { [native code] }]
}

How is it possible to have an object with inheritance that does not correctly overwrite a property in the parent?
Or is my expectation wrong that there should not be two different message properties?
After all, this is a standard object and not a custom implementation.

Within a prototype chain object properties of same name do shadow each other. Thus there is no magic behind a.propName featuring a different value than Object.getPrototypeOf(a).propName which again might have a different value than Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(a)).propName.

They shadow each other, if someone defines a property with the same name on the "child", but why would I do that? I'm confused. I also work with inheritance but have not caused this problem so fare.

I don't have the code, it is a standard Object in JavaScript (Runtime Node 20). As I have written, it is the Error object.

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error, the message property is not coming from the prototype, but only the instance of the Error object itself. By default, its value on the Error object is an empty string.

“They shadow each other, if someone defines a property with the same name on the "child", but why would I do that?” You ~can’t not do that. That’s how assigning to properties works.

@Derek It may well be that they write that. Try it out, the tests show the above... During my JEST Test running no Node 20.12.2 a standard Error object, thrown `throw new Error('...') has 2 independent message properties, an own and one in it's prototyp. I do find that strange.

@Ry- Are you sure? I wrote a test and my classes share a message property that is not available twice: https://github.com/MBurchard/bit-log/blob/demo/error-issue/src/tests/prototyp.spec.ts

@Nabor: this in the parent’s constructor is the same object as this in the child’s – setting properties on it still creates properties on the end object (which is good, because otherwise setting a property in one instance of Parent would affect all other instances). What Error has that you don’t is Parent.prototype.message = ''.

@Ry- I totally agree with you, in the Error object there is prototype.message, but I don't understand it. As I know and expect inheritance (my example shows it) there is a single message property. Why did they make two in the Error object?

@Nabor: I don’t know the (possibly historical) reason that message in particular is defined on Error.prototype. Note that !Object.hasOwn(new Error(), 'message'), though, so it’s one way to implement a default value for a property.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@Nabor ... The all property logging that you implemented shows perfectly fine the shadowing of properties, as I did already point to in my former comment. An error instance like with ...const err = new Error('This is a test error');... features message as own property which does shadow the Error prototype's message property with the latter of cause being an empty string value by default since the prototype object has to be unspecific about a default message. Everything you showed works according to the rules of the prototypal inheritance as implemented by JavaScript/EcmaScript.

@PeterSeliger You are absolutely right, everything works the way it was implemented at the time. However, I would like to point out that it doesn't work the way you might expect if you are used to object-orientated language. In my example, I think I have shown quite well that it can be done differently. Which of the two corresponds more to the expected behaviour is up to everyone to decide.

@Nabor ... "... if you are used to object-orientated language" ... oh, the way ECMAScript/JavaScript implements prototypes amongst its other OO features, does fulfill perfectly fine every single aspect of an object oriented language. And switching from a class based background to a prototype based language should not be such a great challenge. And in case you are in need of real good answers about how JS achieves OO and how the prototype chain, late binding, delegation and closures work you could ask another, very specific, question about it.

@PeterSeliger yes, please give me a really good example why one should use a shadowed field and how to use it. For me, this.something feels naturally or obj.something. I haven't even used obj.prototype.something in the last 25 years. There was no need. But again, I accept your opinion that it makes total sense to you, but I would also appreciate the same respect if someone says it feels weird.

@Nabor ...There is an enormous amount of real good enterprise code that relies on exactly this core feature of JS. I won't add any additional example because this is how inheritance, based on prototypes, does work ... In case a property/method does not exist for an object it was called on look it up at that object's prototype object, and continue this pattern until the property/method has been found or the end of the prototype chain has been reached". It works in fact so pretty well that JS is capable of implementing the class paradigm based on constructors, implicit and explicit delegation.

@Nabor ... Regarding ... " I haven't even used obj.prototype.something" ... one does not need to because accessing this.something or obj.something leads to an automatic lookup in case something is not the very object's own property. Thus directly accessing this.something or obj.something is perfectly fine as long as something resides somewhere along an object's prototype chain.

Not if you use the standard JavaScript Error Object ;)

@Nabor Fwiw Error is odd for historical reasons and .message is one of these quirks, but you aren't supposed to deal with Error.prototype under normal circumstances. You needed this for custom error classes in ES5. It is extensible since ES6 and class extends Error is treated in a special way by JS engines to make it work smoothly

@EstusFlask please write your Comment as Answer, that I can mark it as accepted.

@Nabor Sure, will possibly help other readers

The way Error instance behaves in this example is expected for prototypal inheritance, this needs to be taken into account, another answer addresses this. But this not representative in general and is specific to Error.
Error is odd for historical reasons, as well as some other legacy native constructor functions. They can be identified by their allowed usage, Error(). This is different for classes like Promise that are forced to use new.
Error.prototype isn't supposed to be accessed under normal circumstances. It was needed to implement custom error classes in ES5. But Error is extensible since ES6, class extends Error is treated in a special way by JavaScript engines to make it work smoothly.
Error.prototype.message is one of these quirks. As noted in the comments, prototypal inheritance is used to make it a default value for error.message:


let e = Error('error');
console.log(e.message); // 'error'
e.message = undefined;
console.log(e.message); // undefined
delete e.message;
console.log(e.message); // ''



It wouldn't be implemented this way in modern JavaScript. In the semantics of ES6 classes, a prototype object holds class methods and accessor properties, not values.


How is it possible to have an object with inheritance that does not correctly overwrite a property in the parent? Or is my expectation wrong that there should not be two different message properties?

It sounds like your misconception here is that an object with a prototype chain has a copy of a set of properties associated with each prototype, and that an assignment will look up and modify the corresponding one. That’s not how it works; creating an object using a prototype does not copy the prototype, and the default effect of assigning new values to properties is to create those properties on the end object, shadowing any prototype ones with the same name.


const proto = {foo: 1};
const obj = Object.create(proto);  // {} -> {foo: 1} chain

console.log(obj.foo, Object.hasOwn(obj, 'foo'));  // 1 false

obj.foo = 2;
console.log(obj.foo, Object.hasOwn(obj, 'foo'));  // 2 true
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj).foo);  // 1, prototype unchanged
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj) === proto);  // true, no copy

delete obj.foo;
console.log(obj.foo, Object.hasOwn(obj, 'foo'));  // 1 false




Could it be because of how the inheritance is realised? Are there old and new ways? I have linked an example code in the comment above, which shows why I had a certain expectation and am confused.

@Nabor: No, there aren’t old and new ways. Note that Error.prototype doesn’t need to have message to work, it just does. More details in the reply to the comment on the question.
